# Events log and comparison using Firebase Analytics for mobile app (iOS and Android)

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I used google analytics in my mobile application to track log events, but google analytics will be sunsetting from october 31. I had implemented the firebase analytics in my mobile application and I can able to track custom and standard log events. But in firebase analytics it is not providing a option to view count for particular property.

For Example: My application is an audio player APP. when user plays any song I will send song category, location(city name) and song title to google analytics. User can listen same category songs from different cities. Using google analytics I can able to see in a particular city count for the song title and count for the category too using the comparison of Event action, Event Label and Event Category. Also google analytics providing a feasibility to tap on each property to look into the details.

I am looking for the same using Firebase Analytics. Could someone help me whether it is possible to compare events using Firebase Analytics?
Or
A tool to match the google analytics dashboard where i can see the count for song title and category for the respective city.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> "Also google analytics providing a feasibility to tap on each property
>   to look into the details."

- It is possible to "register" parameters in Firebase Analytics to get some additional details in the firebase dashboard.
- https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en

---

> Or A tool to match the google analytics dashboard where i can see the count for song title and category for the respective city

I believe that your best bet (while remaining with Firebase Analytics) to cross compare parameters would be to enable BigQuery export for your data and then query the exported database or use Google Visual Studio to visualize said queries.

- https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/using-bigquery-and-firebase-analytics-to-understand-your-mobile-app